# What is the difference between `UIbutton.setImage` and changing `UIbutton.imageView`?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What is the difference between `UIbutton.setImage` and changing `UIbutton.imageView`?

```
buttonA.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "name")

buttonA.setImage(UIImage(named: "name"), for: .normal)
```

When I try to use `setImage` and then try to get it's position using `frame.origin.x`, the position returned are not what I expected and so I used `.imageView?.image` approach. But when I use that, I observed that clicking on the button changes the image for a brief time before continuing.

Comment: `for: state`, that's the important part of the method. Also, the UIButton has a subview for the `UIImageView`, so the frame of the button might not be the same as the imageView. You can have insets too.

Answer (score 0):

1. the function offers you the ability to set different icons for various states

```swift
    setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal) //normal state
    setImage(disabledImage, for: .disabled) //disable UI representation
```

2. UIButton.imageView according to documentation read-only property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624033-imageview

Comment: Quoting the same doc "Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write."

Answer (score 0):

For some clarification...

If you set the `.image` property directly:

```
buttonA.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "name")
```

You have not *informed the button class* that it has a new image property.

The same thing applies to setting the title:

```
buttonA.titleLabel?.text = "My Title"
```

That will change the text of the title label, but only until the next UI update... at which point UIKit will use the value assigned via:

```
buttonA.setTitle("Button A", for: .normal)
```

That's why it's important to use both `.setImage(...)` and `.setTitle(...)` instead of setting the property itself.